# Generating an even random range in Netezza

Tags: sql, random, netezza

Netezza says that its random() function generates a float between 0.0 and 0.99999...
I'm trying to generate random ints within a range (e.g., between 5 and 10).  The internet told me to use an equation like this to scale a fraction to a number in a range:

```
select f,count(*) from (
    select CAST(5 + random() * (10-5) as INT) as f
    from table_of_numbers
    where number between 1 and 5000
) x group by 1 order by 1
```

However, when I use that code, the extreme values are under-represented in the sample:

```
F    COUNT
5    486    <---
6    992
7    1057
8    1000
9    937
10   528    <---
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `random()*(10-5)` produces numbers from 0 to 4.99999.  However, you have a range of 6 values (5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10).  So your expression is splitting 5 values across 6 buckets.

Your code is finding that the first and last are half full.  Apparently, the `cast()` operation is rounding the values rather than truncating them (I don't think this is ANSI SQL, but it would explain your observed results).  This masks the problem.

Try this:

```
select CAST(4.5 + random() * (10-5+1) as INT)
```

In other databases, something like this should work:

```
select CAST(5 + random() * (10-5+1) as INT)
```

Comment: You could also explicitly qualify it with the Netezza `FLOOR` function: `FLOOR(RANDOM() * 6) + 5` will give you an pretty even random distribution of numbers 5 through 10.

Answer (score 1):

This slightly modified query produced an even distribution of random numbers from 5 to 10 (inclusively) on a big table (~70m rows) on my environment:

```
select f, count(*) from (
    select 5 + floor(random() * 5.99)::int as f
    from some_big_table
) x group by 1 order by 1;

F   COUNT
5   11659920
6   11663534
7   11665070
8   11668845
9   11665256
10  11549193
```

The key here is to tell the system to round the random number down to the nearest integer value.